# How to check current breakpoint function in TRACE32?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I'm trying to check if the program stopped in a function in a TRACE32.

I know I can see the the functions in FRAME window but no idea how to copy them to a variable inside my script.

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the name of the function, where the program counter points to with:

```
PRINT sYmbol.FUNCTION(PP())
```

(Instead of printing the result you can also assign it to a macro.)

So one approach to check if you've stopped in function *myFunc()* would be:

```
PRINT STRing.ComPare(sYmbol.FUNCTION(PP()),"*\myFunc")
```

Another way is to check if the program counter is inside the first and last address of your function *myFunc()*:

```
PRINT (ADDRESS.OFFSET(sYmbol.BEGIN(`myFunc`))<=Register(PP))&&(Register(PP)<=ADDRESS.OFFSET(sYmbol.END(`myFunc`)))
```

Comment: What do you refer to when you say sYmbol.FUNCTION(PP()) ? what means PP() in that context ?

Comment: From ide_func.pdf:
"PP() returns the address of the program pointer, which consists of the access class + the CPU program counter
(PC). Additionally, the function PP() returns the space ID as a hex value if SYStem.Option.MMUSPACES is set to ON."

But if your TRACE32 does not yet have PP() you can also use P:Register(PP) or even P:Register(PC) in most cases. So you would get `PRINT sYmbol.FUNCTION(P:Register(PP))`